# Can I mock a private method or what is the correct way to test this POST method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC app and wanted to create some unit tests and I quickly ran into the problem below. Is there some sort of way to use MOQ and say 'When the private method GETCLIENTIP is run then return 'xxx'')?

Since right now it is uses parts of HttpContext that of course the unit test does not have.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]TriageCase TriageCase)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Get the IP address from the request
        TriageCase.ipAddress = this.GetClientIP(Request);

        _log.Info("IP Address = " + TriageCase.ipAddress);
    }
}

public void Verify_Not_A_Suicide()
{
    TriageCaseRepository repository = new TriageCaseRepository();
    var controller = new TriageCasesController(repository);
    //This will not work because I must mock a private method in the controller?
    HttpResponseMessage result = controller.Post(new TriageCase());
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at FakeItEasy?  It should answer some of your questions.  That being said, ASP.NET MVC is notoriously hard to debug.  Consider injecting certain logical pieces using a DI/IOC container such as Simple Injector, this will make testing MUCH easier.

Comment: The app does use IoC for the controller constructor repository.. but the method I want to mock has nothing to do with that.. its just a private method that uses some HttpContext

Comment: I see adding this helps but not sure why  controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, right from nasty complicated ones to simple **traded-off** ones. here are some:

- you could make the `GetClientIP` method agnostic of `HttpContext`. and then make it internal. mark the controller assembly with `InternalsVisibleTo` and put the unit test assembly path.

making the method agnostic of `HttpContext` saves you from having a `HttpContextBase` (the abstract http context class from 3.5 onwards for to enable testing) and provide mocking etc. (btw, you should think about it. especially for MVC) pass the specific string as the parameter to the method. e.g. The specific server variable string.

- you could make the `GetClientIP` method receive HttpContextBase as the parameter and then make it internal. mark the controller assembly with `InternalsVisibleTo` and put the unit test assembly path.

in your controller action, you need to call this method as `this.GetClientIP(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))`

your unit tests can set mockable context. and whats more, you can set expectations on the context as to if the Request property was called, or if the ip address related server variable call was made. (not to mention the straight ip address value verification)

- you could use FakeItEasy or Microsoft Moles etc. to create private accessors for  private methods. i normally refrain from that.
- you could write an interface base `INetworkUtility` which has a method to give you the IP Address. your controller could use this interface. and it could be tested in isolation as well.
- you could have a public helper class to get the ip address, which can be unit tested.

as you can see, every solution has some trade-off you need to do.

getting IP Address from the Request object is an isolated piece of logic irrespective of mvc or web api or asp web forms. (still web specific though) so it doesn't harm to have it as helper methods or interface based helper methods.

personally, i prefer the Internal approach, (since it is almost private) and doesn't need much code change.

Answer (score 2):

In proper TDD fashion you don't Unit Test "private" or "internal" methods. Only the public interface is used within Unit Tests. If you Unit Test a private/internal method then you are tying your unit tests too tightly to that specific implementation.

What should be done instead is use Dependency Injection to inject a class/interface that implements the "dependent" functionality that you are needing to unit test. This will help further modularize your code thus making it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I general don't try to test private methods. It just gets messy - test the input and output of an action...

Either do the **Dependency Injection** thing or think about a "test double" or "accessor" class...

For a *test double* - make the `private` method a `protected` and then you inherit the controller and manually mock out inputs or outputs as required. I am not stating whether this is better or worse than Ioc, I am saying this is *another* way to do it.

```
protected virtual string ExecuteIpnResponse(string url)
{
  var ipnClient = new WebClient();
  var ipnResponse = ipnClient.DownloadString(url);
  return ipnResponse;
}
```

I did a post on this testing style recently for checking a paypal call. 
http://viridissoftware.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/paypal-ipn-payment-notification-example-in-c/